# Grouping an array and get sum

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have the following setup.

```
Invoice has_many Jobs has_many Tasks belongs_to user
```

I want to get all `User`s for an `Invoice` that have tasks and sum up their quantities

```
class Invoice < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :jobs
end

class Job < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :invoice 
  has_many :tasks      
end

class Task < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :job                   
  belongs_to :user     
end
```

Here is what I got

```
@invoice = Invoice.find(params[:id])
jobs = @invoice.jobs.joins(:tasks)
        .select('tasks.user_id, (sum(tasks.quantity)*jobs.price) as total')
        .group('tasks.user_id, jobs.id')
        .order('tasks.user_id')
```

I get this, which is close to what I want

```
- !ruby/object:Job
  attributes:
    user_id: '1'
    total: '60.00'
- !ruby/object:Job
  attributes:
    user_id: '1'
    total: '50.00'
- !ruby/object:Job
  attributes:
    user_id: '2'
    total: '120.00'
- !ruby/object:Job
  attributes:
    user_id: '2'
    total: '100.00'
```

How can I group this by `user_id` and sum up the total so that I have something like this?

```
user_id: 1
total: 110
user_id: 2
total: 220
```

Comment: could you please clarify the relationships between your models. how `task` and `jobs` are connected?

Comment: this seems like a job better fitted for raw SQL or Arel rather than using ActiveRecord.

Comment: Didn't you think about SQL views?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

thansk for your answers.

I managed to solve this with

```
user_totals = jobs.to_a.group_by(&:user_id).map{ |user_id,jobs| {:user_id => user_id.to_i, :total => jobs.sum {|j| j.total.to_f} }} 
=> [{:user_id=>1, :total=>110.0}, {:user_id=>2, :total=>220.0}]
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe just a simple each loop creating a hash will do?

```
user_totals = Hash.new(0)
jobs.each do |job|
  user_totals[job.user_id] += job.total
end
```

This will give you:

```
user_totals =  {"1":110, "2":220}
```

Answer (score 0):

use `group_by`

```
Hash[jobs.group_by(&:user_id).map {|user_id, jobs|  [user_id, jobs.reduce{ |m, job| m+job.total] }]
```

Something like that (I haven't tested it, so it might not work as it is)